# Is there an NHibernate killer out there?

Tags: nhibernate, orm, domain-driven-design

This is probably a long shot.

In the .NET world, has anyone found an ORM (Commercial or Open) that has the flexibility of NHibernate to support domain driven design with good Linq support?  Linq to sql is dead, Entity Framework doesnt yet support POCO's, lazy load or object first development very well, and none of the old stand bys such as LLBLGen seem to either.

Anyone find anything new and exciting in the ORM market?

Thanks!

Comment: Who says LINQ to SQL is dead?  Did Microsoft release a patch to make it suddenly stop working?

Comment: Also, what about NHibernate is causing you to look for alternatives?  If it's the XML mappings, have a look at Fluent NHibernate.  If you don't care for that either, have a look at Castle ActiveRecord, which is NHibernate-based but makes the mapping even easier and also abstracts away some of the session management.

Comment: @Kyralessa: LinqToSql is not dead, but Microsoft is putting its muscle behind Entity Framework (did you count the number of PDC 2009 sessions on EF vs. LinqToSql?).  NHibernate's Linq provider is a work in progress and that seems to matter to fregas.

Comment: NHibernate overall is very complex.  I do use Fluent but there seems to be so many show stoppers such as incomplete LINQ support and general complexity (even after using it for 3 years) that slows down development.  I just want to see if theres something new/better on the scene.

Linq2Sql has better query support but doesnt do complex mappings or DDD very well.

Comment: Interestingly, not only is LINQ to SQL not dead, but it's used in Windows Phone 8 as the primary data access method.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See [ORMBattle.NET](http://ormbattle.net) - it won't exactly answer your question (btw, I hardly admit this is possible), but there is some info on quality of LINQ support.

Note (or disclaimer): I'm one of persons related to creation of ORMBattle.NET, as well as one of [DataObjects.Net](http://wiki.dataobjects.net) authors.

Comment: Thanks for the disclaimer, I really appreciate it.  Extra information related to the original question: LLBLGen asked not to be listed on ORMBattle.NET.

Comment: I clearly had no intention of hiding this fact. So it's really better to simply repeat it everywhere where this isn't absolutely obvious.

Answer (score 2):

Which version of the .NET Framework are you talking about?  3.5?  4.0?

There are quite a few ORMs out there and some of the commercial ones may in fact meet your needs (or be working on new releases that meet your needs).  Competing against both NHibernate and Entity Framework from a commercial perspective is pretty daunting.  Microsoft made it much harder than necessary to write a Linq provider, which is why so few ORMs have one.  Writing a domain driven design oriented ORM that supports multiple database vendors is also a pretty steep hill to climb.

NHibernate certainly has all the momentum right now, but that doesn't mean it's invincible.  It's hard to compete with free & open source software that has a multi-year head start, even for a company with the financial resources of Microsoft.

I think you may just need to be patient.  NHibernate's Linq provider is improving and the other ORM vendors are working hard on improving their offerings as well.  Things could change significantly in the next two years or so.

Answer (score 1):

No, I don't know of any. Because NHibernate is popular and very good at what it does, and EF is likely to pick up most of the remainder (particularly devs that don't want to stray from Microsoft-supplied frameworks), the barrier to entry for a new player is very high. Another ORM would need to add something significant over and above what NHibernate currently offers in order to get any reasonable level of interest.

If there was an open source project that wanted to deliver better Linq support in an ORM, in my opinion it would have greater success contributing to NHibernate Linq rather than attempting to build its own framework from scratch.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't call it a "NHibernate killer", but SubSonic works well. It's simple to use, allows you to choose between using the Active Record pattern and the Repository pattern. It supports POCOs, lets you use object-first development and setting up lazy-loading is easy enough.

Answer (score 1):

CQRS could be considered an NHibernate killer.  The basic premise is that your domain objects are not used to support your read model and application queries.  As such, you can start using something more like a document store to hold your aggregate or even use event sourcing.  To update your read model, you have it listen to the events published by your aggregate so that it can update itself accordingly.  Using this architectural style we have been able to eliminate the our reliance upon NHibernate.  Now if we decide to use an RDBMS, it's because of the strengths of the database rather than as the default choice.

Comment: It still seems like you would need NHibernate or another ORM for basic CRUD stuff.  For advanced reporting I agree its not really the best tool...but you could argue for Entity Framework

Comment: NHibernate becomes overkill at that point.  There are a bunch of "mini ORMs" that are popping up--even an open source one from the Stack Exchange guys.